# Finding support of a function

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, logic, propositional-calculus

Let $X$ be a set and $f$ be a function from $X$ to 
$\{0, 1\}$, the field with two
elements. The support of $f$ is the set $f ^ {-1}$
(1), which we denote by $\DeclareMathOperator{\supp}{supp}\supp(f)$.
For a collection $F$ of such functions define $\:\supp(F) = \bigcap_{f∈F} \supp(f)$

Note that when $F = ∅, \:\supp(F) = X$, and that for such functions,
$f$ is the characteristic function of its support, i.e., $f = χ_{\supp(f)}$.
Find the supports of $f · g$, $1 − f$, $f + g − f · g$, and $1 − f + f · g$ in terms of
the supports of $f$ and $g$.

Do now know where to start. Will be helpful to get at least the first one to see how it works.

Answer (score 1):

I give you a couple of examples.

Let $f \cdot g \colon X \to \{0,1\}$ be the function defined by $(f \cdot g) (x) = f(x) \cdot g(x)$ for all $x \in X$.
The support of $f \cdot g$ is the *intersection* of the supports of $f$ and $g$.
Indeed, by definition of support, 
\begin{align}
\operatorname{supp}(f \cdot g) &= \{x \in X \mid f(x) \cdot g(x) = 1\} \\
 &= \{x \in X \mid f(x) = 1 \text{ and } g(x) = 1\} \\
 &= \{x \in X \mid f(x) = 1\} \cap \{x \in X \mid g(x) = 1\} = \operatorname{supp}(f) \cap \operatorname{supp}(g).
\end{align}

Let $1 \!-\! f \colon X \to \{0,1\}$ be the function defined by $(1 \!-\! f)(x) = 1 - f(x)$ for all $x \in X$.
The support of $1 \!-\!f$ is the *complement* of the support of $f$.
Indeed, by definition of support, 
\begin{align}
\operatorname{supp}(1 \!-\! f) &= \{x \in X \mid f(x) = 0\} \\
 &= \{x \in X \mid f(x) \neq 1\} \\
 &= X \smallsetminus \{x \in X \mid f(x) = 1\} \ = X \smallsetminus \operatorname{supp}(f).
\end{align}

Comment: then will the following be true: supp(1-f + f * g) = X∖supp(f) or supp(g) ??

Comment: @Amalya - What does it mean "or" in your comment? It should be a set-theoretic operation. Anyway, you had the right intuition.

Comment: I meant "union" by "or". i am getting it right, yes?

Comment: @Amalya - Yes, you're right. What about $\text{supp}(f + g - f \!\cdot\! g)$?

Comment: (X∖supp(f) ∩ supp(g)) ∪ (X∖supp(g) ∩ supp(f)). is it right?

Comment: @Amalya - Perfect, well done! This is is the [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) of $\text{supp}(f)$ and $\text{supp}(g)$.